# Big O of finding out if a binary tree is balanced (From CTCI Book)

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, big-o

In Cracking the Coding Interview 6th Edition there's a question (4.4) where you're suppose to find out if a binary tree is balanced, where balanced in this case means if any side is deeper than the other by more than 1.

I solved this recursively like this:

```py
def isBalanced(root):
  return abs(getDepth(root.left) - getDepth(root.right)) > 1

def getDepth(node):
  if node is None:
    return 0
  return 1 + max([getDepth(node.left), getDepth(node.right)])
```

So to walk through it. It recursively check each side of each node and pass it up to the root, if the root then have a higher difference between the left and right subtrees than 1, it returns False, else True.

In the answer section of the book the author writes the following about this type of solution:

> Although this works, it's not very efficient. On each node, we recurse through it's entire subtree. This means that getHeight is called repeatedly on the same nodes. The algorithm is O(N log N) since each node is "touched" once per node above it.

The books solution is the following:

```java
int getHeight(TreeNode root) {
  if (root == null) return -1;
  return Math.max(getHeight(root.left), getHeight(root.right)) + 1;
}

boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
  if (root == null) return true;

  int heightDiff = getHeight(root.left) - getHeight(root.right);
  if (Math.abs(heightDiff) < 1) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return isBalanced(root.left) && isBalanced(root.right);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't understand how this is the case. In my mind, the algorithm only checks the level below it. Each node is **not** checked multiple times. When I look at this algorithm it is O(N).

Can someone help me confirm if I understood the Big-O of this algorithm correctly, or if I missed something?

Comment: In what way was the feedback given to your solution? It seems to me that your solution does not do what the feedback suggests, and has a time complexity of O(N), i.e. it touches each node once.

Comment: Your solution does not check if the *child* sub-trees are balanced; although I don't see how that would change the overall complexity.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog truncating based on the solution of a subtree does improve performance, but in the case of a balanced tree, the work done is still O(n), which makes this solution O(n) (which is what you're saying)

Comment: I added the code example from the book that they claim is O(N log N). I do notice that they do recursive calls on `isBalanced()` but I'm not sure why that's needed.

Comment: I had a suspicion that this is exactly what the author did. One can avoid the second set of calls by incorporating the balance-checking functionality into `getHeight`.

Comment: @MarcusLind Note how I was wrong about the things I said, if you can unmark my answer as accepted I will delete it after that. (I cannot delete accepted answer unfortunately)

Answer (score 7):

Let's write the time complexity function of `isBalanced` as `T(n)`. The average-case recurrence relation is therefore:

[image]

Where the `O(n)` comes from the two calls to `getHeight`, which we know to be `O(n)`. Therefore, using the Master theorem, the overall complexity of `isBalanced` is `O(n log n)`.

Your solution does not call `isBalanced` on the child nodes, which means the `O(n)` in the relation above is replaced by an `O(1)`, giving `O(n)` overall (again from the Master theorem). It does not however (as an obvious consequence!) check that the child nodes are balanced, so is incorrect.

The problem with CTCI's naive solution is that it effectively calls `getHeight` *again* for each child node (by calling `isBalanced`), which is unnecessary. One can incorporate the balance-checking functionality into `getHeight` to obtain a solution in `O(n)`:

```
int balance_internal(TreeNode root)
{
    // change the specification slightly to return 0 for a leaf
    // ... and -1 for an unbalanced node
    if (root == null) return 0;

    int left_h = balance_internal(root.left);
    int right_h = balance_internal(root.right);

    // if either node is unbalanced
    if (left_h == -1 || right_h == -1)
        return -1;

    // return max height as before
    // ... but now with the knowledge that both child nodes are balanced
    return Math.abs(left_h - right_h) > 1 ? -1 : 1 + Math.max(left_h, right_h);
}

boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root)
{
    return (balance_internal(root) > -1);
}
```

Although perhaps not as *graceful* as the provided solution, this does not create duplicate calls to child nodes, and instead reuses the results from the first set of calls. The recurrence relation is thus the *same* as that of your own solution, giving `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm time complexity is `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1`. Hence, time complexity of your algorithm would be `T(n) = O(n)`. However, the correctness of your algorithm is under question.